# Why my web application works on Glassfish, but doesn't on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have following Maven Project:

pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <param>local</param>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>todoapi</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/${param}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ca.gatin.todoapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

REST Resource

```
@Path("/accounts")
public class AccountResource {
    AccountService accountService = new AccountService();

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String wsTest() {
        return "Web Service works!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accountService.getAccounts();
    }

}
```

and model

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean isActive;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date dateLastModified;

    // required for JAXB
    public Account() {}

...
}
```

When I deploy this project on GlassFish 4.0 all APIs work, but when I deploy it on Tomcat 7 this API works:
http://localhost:8080/todoapi/webapi/accounts/test
, but this one does not work:
http://localhost:8080/todoapi/webapi/accounts
if gives different errors, no matter what I try:

> com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException MIME media type application/json was not found.
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,

Comment: post your error/stack trace

Comment: I believe that Glassfish has some JARs which are not included in Tomcat by default.  From looking at your POM, there is even a section which says to uncomment to get JSON support.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: For now, I get this error, when I try to run it on Tomcat: Oct 11, 2015 11:01:38 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<ca.gatin.todoapi.model.Account>.

Comment: Now my Maven project can run successfully on Tomcat and Glassfish.

Comment: The thing that confused me is that for Jersey 2 you use  org.glassfish.jersey... path, and I thought if there is word glassfish it should work only with GlassFish server, and I tried not not use it on Tomcat. But it was wrong, I can use it on both.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your error says it all:

> ```
> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json
> ```

When you use JAXRS based frameworks, you need message writers to generate json/xml. Few web/application servers provide default message writers for example in your case Glassfish does. But not all servers do provide, as in your second case , Tomcat does not.

You need to add dependency for message json message writers such as jersey-json,etc. As you are using maven so this should do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>{latest_version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, I have added:   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: oops, one second, I did some other changes and it worked! Let me check what exactly solved the issue.

Comment: I have uncommented this and it just worked:   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: So there was not need to add jersey-json, because it is Jersey 1, but I am using org.glassfish.jersey which is Jersey 2